# Cumulative sum running on all the columns in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

I have a spreadsheet with a lot of columns for each year, and I need a formula that I can apply on the entire table to update the cumulative sum. Better explanation in the picture below:

[image]

The top part is how I have the table currently. The bottom part is how I need the table to be, and be able to make updates any time to any cell.

At the moment I am just having a separate 'table' of all that, where I run this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(COLUMN(B3:J3),"<="&COLUMN(B3:J3),B3:J3))
```

What I need is this applied to the entire table, so whenever I make an update in any cell, it will update and run the entire cumulative sum across the years for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your current solution is best you can have in Google Sheets by using internal formula functions. a small improvement can be done to have it under one formula if you stack individual rows (in your case pasted in B11 cell - based on image) like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 SUMIF(COLUMN(B3:J3),"<="&COLUMN(B3:J3),B3:J3);
 SUMIF(COLUMN(B4:J4),"<="&COLUMN(B4:J4),B4:J4);
 SUMIF(COLUMN(B5:J5),"<="&COLUMN(B5:J5),B5:J5)})
```

if you seek for instant cumulative calculation on a given range fully editable - it could be (if) possible only with a script.

Comment: Thank you. But can I achieve what I want in Excel though ?

Comment: probably yes with VBA scripting